# Novel about a starship that crashes on a world of primarily female leadership?

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

Spaceship crashes in the northern part of a world which has primarily women leadership.  Spaceship crew assimilate and build a kingdom.

The new kingdom is built around the technology but the technology is finite so they have to work with what they have and assimilate into the existing kingdom. I believe there are some angel references? I loved this series but I can't find it anywhere! It is driving me insane!

Comment: Edited for clarity, I hope I maintained the intent of the question, but some of the ambiguous pronouns were hard to place.  Please feel free to revert if I've edited something incorrectly.

Comment: Any further details such as character names, when you read it, or additional details may help.

Comment: Was "Cat Women on the Moon" a novel first?

Answer (score 12):

This reminds me of something by Modesitt. The Saga of Recluce, one of the books describes the coming of an advanced alien race called angels.

check the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Saga_of_Recluce)

Comment: Yup. "Fall of Angels" is the one that describes the landing. http://www.amazon.com/Fall-Angels-Saga-Recluce-Modesitt/dp/0812538951

Answer (score 3):

Is it possibly David Weber's [Heirs of the Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heirs_of_Empire)?  It's the third in the *Empire from the Ashes* series, following *Mutineer's Moon* and *The Armageddon Inheritance*.

The spaceship contains 5 people (4 human teens and an alien) who are seen as Angels by the local, very low tech, civilization.  The book details their struggle to help the northern regions rebel against an oppressive central rule, in order to access the technology which remains from the planet's original colonization (now worshiped as 'holy relics' by the people of the world).

You can find the entire series [free online](http://baencd.thefifthimperium.com/09-AtAllCostsCD/AtAllCostsCD/Empire%20From%20the%20Ashes/index.htm) as part of [Baen Book's Baen CD collection](http://baencd.thefifthimperium.com/).

Comment: There is an important difference: the existing kingdom on the planet is NOT female-led, however the northern region rebellion IS led by one of the off-world human women.